# Unable to come up with reason for the given for loop (Python 3.11)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
s=0

for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
    s+=a[-1]
print('sum=',s)
```

The output for the above code is

```
1
2
3
3
sum= 9
```

Could you explain why? A dry run would be appreciated.

I tried to come up with a dry run but I did not understand the output at all.

Comment: You're using a list index as a *loop variable*, so the value of each element in `a` will be written to `a[-1]` (i.e. the last index of the list). The code is therefore equivalent to `for v in a: a[len(a) - 1] = v`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I use a list index as an indexing variable in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644201/why-can-i-use-a-list-index-as-an-indexing-variable-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to explain it with an exmaple.

Assume this snippet:

```py
for i in a:
    ...
```

In this code, in each iterate, `i` will be an element of a. It's like: `i=a[0]`, `i=a[1]`, ... .

Now when you have this code:

```py
for a[-1] in a:
    ...
```

It's like you are doing this in each iterate: `a[-1] = a[0]`, `a[-1] = a[1]`, `a[-1] = a[2]` and ...

So you are changing last element each time, and when your iterate ends, your last element would be 3.

Answer (score 2):

Change code to next you can understand it clearly:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
s=0

for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
    print(a)
    s+=a[-1]
print('sum=',s)
```

**execution:**

```
1
[1, 2, 3, 1]
2
[1, 2, 3, 2]
3
[1, 2, 3, 3]
3
[1, 2, 3, 3]
sum= 9
```

You could see with every loop, the last item of that list be updated with `1`, `2`, `3` (NOTE: list[-1] in python means last item of list), and when you loop it for the last time, the value is nolonger `4`, but `3`.